# WinForms прозрачные Textbox'ы

Tags: winforms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.sds;
            AuthGUI();

        }
        public void AuthGUI()
            {
            label1 = new Label();
            label1.Location = new Point(160, 74);
            label1.Text = "СРИНДЕР";
            label1.BackColor = TransparencyKey;
            this.Controls.Add(label1);
            bt1 = new Button();
            bt1.Name = "button1";
            bt1.Text = "Регистрация";
            bt1.Width = 129;
            bt1.Height = 42;
            bt1.Location = new Point(123, 159);
            bt1.Click += this.bt1_reg;
            bt2 = new Button();
            bt2.Name = "button2";
            bt2.Text = "Вход";
            bt2.Width = 129;
            bt2.Height = 44;
            bt2.Location = new Point(123, 244);
            //bt2.Click += this.bt_Click;
            this.Controls.Add(bt1);
            this.Controls.Add(bt2);

        }

        public void bt1_reg(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            bt1.Hide();
            bt2.Hide();
            label1.Hide();           
            regGUIload();
        }
        public void regGUIload()
        {
            labelreg1 = new Label();
            labelreg2 = new Label();
            labelreg3 = new Label();
            labelreg1.Location = new Point(171, 62);
            labelreg2.Location = new Point(171, 124);
            labelreg3.Location = new Point(171, 178);
            labelreg1.Text = "Логин";
            labelreg2.Text = "Пароль";
            labelreg3.Text = "E-mail";
            labelreg1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            labelreg2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            labelreg3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            textbox1 = new TextBox();
            textbox2 = new TextBox();
            textbox3 = new TextBox();
            textbox1.MaxLength = 16;
            textbox2.MaxLength = 24;
            textbox3.MaxLength = 36;
            textbox1.BackColor = Color.White;
            textbox1.Location = new Point(135, 89);
            textbox2.Location = new Point(135, 140);
            textbox3.Location = new Point(135, 194);
            regbutton = new Button();
            regbutton.Text = "Регистрация";
            regbutton.Width = 144;
            regbutton.Height = 44;
            regbutton.Location = new Point(126, 288);
            this.Controls.Add(labelreg1);
            this.Controls.Add(labelreg2);
            this.Controls.Add(labelreg3);
            this.Controls.Add(textbox1);
            this.Controls.Add(textbox2);
            this.Controls.Add(textbox3);
            this.Controls.Add(regbutton);
        }
    }
```

Создавал панель регистрации, но у меня почему то прозрачные текстбоксы. В чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в конструктор формы еще одну строку:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
    }
```

И заодно, чтобы надписи не налезали на текстбоксы, поднимите текстбоксы наверх - добавьте в конец метода `regGUIload`

```
textbox1.BringToFront();
textbox2.BringToFront();
textbox3.BringToFront();
```